# Java library for thermodynamic calculations

Tags: open-source, library, java

I have been trying to find a java library of the core thermodynamic calculations / formulas.

The closest I got was this:

https://github.com/OpenSourcePhysics/osp/tree/master/src/org/opensourcephysics

And a batch of interesting resources here: https://github.com/iurisegtovich/AwesomeThermodynamics

What I would need is any reasonable subset of for instance [Table of thermodynamic equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_thermodynamic_equations).

Any pointer would be appreaciated.